# CHEF: Generate and register node_name

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo, chefspec

I'm very new to Chef and I don't know how to I can generate and register new node_name. Here what I did:

1) sign up an account at Chef https://manage.chef.io/login and login

2) let's say I have an organization

3) on Chef UI portal, click on Administration and download Starter Kit

4) After I download the Starter Kit, the unzip has 3 files: my-login.pem, knife.rb and my-org-validator.pem

5) I test and I was able to list cookbooks, list client,...

6) When I open knife.rb, I see something like this:

```
# See https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html for more information on knife configuration options

current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "my-login"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/my-login.pem"
validation_client_name   "my-org-validator"
validation_key           "#{current_dir}/my-org-validator.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://api.opscode.com/organizations/my-org"
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
```

now my questions are:

1) if I use the same Start Kit with node_name "my-login", and install it in all my servers, then in Chef UI, it will only show 1 server. I'm looking for a way that I can install Start Kit in all servers with different node_name. How do I do that?

2) Can I generate node_name dynamically using only my-org-validator.pem file?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [learnchef](http://learn.chef.io) to learn the basis (bootstraping a node, managing runlist, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The starter kit is only for your development work station. You don't need to install that on servers that you manage with Chef (in Chef, servers are called nodes). Rather, you should bootstrap a server that you wish to manage with Chef, and once the chef-client is installed (automagically using the knife bootstrap command), Chef Server will become aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your workstation to bootstrap your node. Use -N option to give customize node name.

Execute below command from your workstation. Make sure that you provide correct IP address of your node and username-password to access remotely.

**knife bootstrap IPAddress -x username -P Password -N node_name

Read https://docs.chef.io/knife_bootstrap.html -  for more information.